# Azure function prop_status failed

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm testing the deployment of the sample Azure function on the cloud.

```
from typing import List
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    for event in events:
        #Test
        logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                        event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

But upon checking my ApplicationInsights, I see this instead of the logged info.

```
Category
Function.update_data

EventId
3

EventName
FunctionCompleted

HostInstanceId
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

InvocationId
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

LogLevel
Error

ProcessId
49

prop__executionDuration
103

prop__functionName
Functions.update_data

prop__invocationId
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

prop__status
Failed
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Have you added the connection string of your event hub to the "Application settings" of your function app ?

Comment: I have found the issue to be related to this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/issues/971

Comment: So you solved the problem ? Could you please provide the solution below for other communities reference ?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in this issue raised (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/issues/971)

When creating an event hub trigger in Python through the SDK (azure-function==1.4.0) , the function that is created in the **init**.py file has a parameter called events:

```
def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
```

In the function.json file where the binding is defined, the mapping is called event, not events:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
      {
        "type": "eventHubTrigger",
        "name": "event", #Change this to events
        "direction": "in",
        "eventHubName": "samples-workitems",
        "connection": "",
        "cardinality": "many",
        "consumerGroup": "$Default",
        "dataType": "binary"
      }
    ]
}
```

The function.json needs to be updated to change the name to **events**.